# Custom Product Export proper format

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I used below controller to export Product Information. It export But my problem is all value come only header. How to display proper format

```
public function exportmeAction(){
      try{
        $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//optional for only enabled products
        $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
        ->joinField('qty',
                         'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                         'qty',
                         'product_id=entity_id',
                         '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                         'left');;//optional for products only visible in catalog and search
        $content = '"Product Id","Product Name","Product Sku","Product Url", "Product Image Url","Category Ids","Description","Product Qty","Special Price", "Price"\n';
        foreach ($products as $product){
            $content .= $product->getSku() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getName() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getId() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getProductUrl() . ",";
            $content .= $product->getDescription() . ",";
            $content .= (int)$product->getFinalPrice() . ",";
            $content .= (int)$product->getPrice() . ",";
            $content .= (int)$product->getQty() . ",";
            $content .= (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image') . ",";
            $content .= implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds()) . ",";//change the category separator if needed
            $content .= "\n";
        }
      }

       catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
      }
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Done");
      $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('export.csv', $content, 'text/csv');
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "It export But my problem is all value come only header. How to display proper format"?

Comment: heade should come tilte like produc name, sku etc next prduct detais will come but in my case everything come it as single row only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these changes :

1. remove the extra quote from content header.
2. also remove the extra "," from last content

   ```
   public function exportmeAction(){
     try{

   $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
   $content = "Product Id,Product Name,Product Sku,Product Url,Product Image Url,Category Ids,Description,Product Qty,Special Price, Price\n";
   foreach ($products as $product){
   $content .= $product->getId() . ",";            
   $content .= $product->getName() . ",";
   $content .= $product->getSku() . ",";
   $content .= $product->getProductUrl() . ",";
   $content .= (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image') . ",";
   $content .= implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
   $content .= $product->getDescription() . ",";
   $content .= (int)$product->getQty() . ",";
   $content .= (int)$product->getFinalPrice() . ",";
   $content .= (int)$product->getPrice() . ",";
   $content .= "\n";
   }

     }

      catch (Exception $e) {
       echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
     }
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Done");
    $test->_prepareDownloadResponse('export.csv', $content, 'text/csv');
   ```

   }

Comment: value show irrelevent column price showing image url

Comment: @Kothari, Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();

    $data=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w+');
    $csvHeader = array('ID',"NAME");
    fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($fp, array($row->getId(),$row->getName()), ",");
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

use this code to generate csv in root

Comment: I want to save my local system not sever

Comment: use prepareDownloadResponse() for save it to local